# Block main thread till worker thread terminates

Tags: multithreading, c++11, mutex, semaphore

I am new to c++ and I need to solve following problem

```
/* runs in context of worker thread
void thread1_fun() {                                          
    //body
    //signal_thread2_fun to unblock
}

/* runs in context of main thread*/
void thread2_fun() {
     block on worker thread1_fun and waiting
     //body
}
```

I am sure I need to lock/semaphore/mutex but not sure how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::thread::join().
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join

Edit: If you do not want to wait for the thread to finish, you may be looking for std::condition_variable. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Please note that you still have to call detach or join on the thread before it is destroyed.

Edit 2: I think a condition variable will work in your scenario, because it expresses the intention that one thread should wait until it gets notified.

For the implementation you need to place a mutex and the condition_variable were both threads can access them. Member variables would work if both are member functions of the same class. Otherwise you can pass them a shared_ptr to a struct with the shared data.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also read about condition variable and it works. However my original problem is bit different.

I have edited my original question. basically with my original problem i can not perform detach or join since it is not in my  program control.